# Passing block as method argument is dying in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

So this pattern:

```
def foo(&block)
  block.call
end

foo lambda { puts 'hi' }
```

Is resulting in this:

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`

Using Ruby 1.9.3.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a lambda, just the block:

```
def foo(&block)
  block.call
end

foo { puts 'hi' }
```

If you want to pass a proc, use a normal parameter:

```
def foo(ohai)
  ohai.call
end

foo lambda { puts 'hi' }
```